# Do modern printers store any personal information that should be removed before selling/giving away

Tags: printer, network-printer, laser-printer

Particularly laser printers, do they store any information that should be wiped before selling or giving the printer away? It's network connected, so I'll have to reset that kind of thing, but I'm curious about print history, file names, etc.

We're not talking commercial printers here, just your standard home office laser printers.

Tia

Edit: Printer in question is a dell c1760nw

Comment: Network settings should be deleted. Turn it off for 24 hours to clear any left over spooled prints.  Otherwise you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the printer.  Many (most?) printers have an internal hard disk that supports spooling operations, and information can be (and often is) left on those.  Wiping the disk should be good enough for most purposes, although someone could still access the files even if they were deleted.  So it depends on how paranoid you are; if you're really paranoid, the best way to be sure is to remove the disk and destroy it.

Check the model number to see if it has a hard disk.  If so, at a minimum you should wipe the disk before getting rid of the printer.

Comment: Our commercial printers have drives in them. Consumer printers (the ones I have seen and as the author mentioned) do not have drives in them (again, the ones I have seen and have experience with)

Comment: I think it depends.  Hard disk storage has become cheap enough that more and more printers are including disks, particularly laser printers.  So it's worth checking.

Comment: Printer in question is a dell c1760nw, from what I've researched it doesn't have an internal disk.. but I could be wrong

Comment: No, that one doesn't look like it does.  So just resetting the network settings and letting it sit for a while ought to do it.

Comment: See http://techgenix.com/Do-Your-Printers-Pose-Security-Risk/ , and, as a side-note, some printers also communicate with outside servers, e.g. HP, which order *mandatory* refills. And don't try to print currency to see what happens ;-)